# NameError running a batch file on a python program

Tags: python, batch-file

I am running a python script with bcp to export the data from my local drive to SQL Server. The python script works well when I run it manually on Jupyter notebook. But, when I create a batch file to automatically run the task, I am getting an error.

Below is the batch file:

```
@echo off
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\Untitled1.ipynb" %*
pause
```

And the error that I get while running the batch file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Atom\Desktop\Untitled1.ipynb", line 40, in <module>
    "execution_count": null,
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Kindly advise what could be the issue.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: _"name 'null' is not defined"_. Did you write `Untitled1.ipynb`, or are just running someone's script? If you wrote it, then only you know what `null` is doing there.

Comment: without seeing the code, the first thing that occurs is that `null` is not a python term - you may need `None`. Unless you mean null, in which case you need to assign it in the script.

Comment: @Newbie123 - Please edit your post to include your code.  If you give enough context (especially indicating line 40 and the surrounding lines), somebody is more likely to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [IPython web site](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/notebook.html) (emphasis mine):

> Notebook documents contains the inputs and outputs of a interactive
> session as well as additional text that accompanies the code but is
> **not meant for execution**. In this way, notebook files can serve as a
> complete computational record of a session, interleaving executable
> code with explanatory text, mathematics, and rich representations of
> resulting objects. **These documents are internally JSON files** and are
> saved with the .ipynb extension.